# Onclick doesn't work in Firefox, but in Chrome - yes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

Consider the following code...

```
function getItems(id, menu_id) {
    //some code
}  

$('#group-api').append('<li><a href="#" onclick="getItems(\''+data['group'][i]['id']+'\',\''+menu_id+'\');" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">'+data['group'][i]['menu_group']+'</a></li>');
```

This works if I use Chrome, but not for Firefox. Any solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try the opposite way. Create the element via jQuery, append a `.click()` event on it, and *then* append it to the containter.

Code:

```
function getItems(id, menu_id) {
    // ...
}

$("<li><a href='#' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>" + data['group'][i]['menu_group'] + "</a></li>")
    .appendTo("#group-api")
    .find("a")
    .click(function() {
        getItems(data['group'][i]['id'], menu_id);
    });
```

JSbin mock-up: http://jsbin.com/dosohatawe/1/edit?js,console,output

---

**Reply to comment:**

You always get the last value because you did not use a closure.
Here is your (non-working) example updated with the use of closures:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data['group'].length; i++) {

    var id = data['group'][i]['id'];

    $("<li><a href='#' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>" + data['group'][i]['menu_group'] + "</a></li>")
        .appendTo("#group-api")
        .find("a")
        .click(
            (function(a, b) {
                return function() {
                    getItems(a, b);
                };
            })(id, menu_id)
        );

}
```

I haven't tested it, but I think it *should* work.

Comment: OK, it's working but not in 100%. I've got a loop and the function has always "last" parameters.

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < data['group'].length; i++) {
                           var id = data['group'][i]['id'];
                           $("<li><a href='#' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>" + data['group'][i]['menu_group'] + "</a></li>")
                            .appendTo("#group-api")
                            .find("a")
                            .click(function() {
                                getItems(id, menu_id);
                            });  
                        }

Comment: I have update my post. The issue was that I didn't used a closure in my first solution (forgot about the loop). Haven't tested it, so I hope it works :)